# Even distribution of people to events

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm trying to evenly distribute several people to different events. For example:

```
People    Events

John      10.10.2021 (4 people needed)
Jack      11.10.2021 (2 people needed)
Harry     12.10.2021 (1 people needed)
Charlie   13.10.2021 (3 people needed)
Jacob     14.10.2021 (5 people needed)
```

I want it, so that always the amount of people needed get assigned to the event. In the best case, every person gets assigned the same amount of times.

How can I achieve this in javascript / typescript?

Comment: Kindly add a code or whatever you have tried till the time so that people can help you.

Comment: Please, provide more details. E.g. : if there are 51 people how you want to distribute them? [4, 2, 1, 3, 5],  [4, 2, 1, 3, 5] ... until there are no people left?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like this maybe:

```js
const people = ['John', 'Jack', 'Harry', 'Charlie', 'Jacob']
const events = [{date: '10.10.2021', nr: 4}, {date: '11.10.2021', nr: 2},
  {date: '12.10.2021', nr: 1}, {date: '13.10.2021', nr: 3}, {date: '14.10.2021', nr: 5}]
const ppl = []
people.forEach(p => ppl.push({'name': p, 'assigned': 0}))
const arr = []
events.forEach(e => {
  let ex = {[e.date]: []}
  arr.push(ex)
  for(let i = 0; i < e.nr; i++) {
    let min = Math.min(...ppl.map(p => p.assigned))
    let pe = ppl.filter(p => p.assigned === min)
    ex[e.date].push(pe[0].name)
    pe[0].assigned++
  }
})
console.log(...arr)
```

Comment: Yeah, thanks. This really helped me out.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `map()` to loop through events and add people to them by `slicing` the array of people. You could add logic for them to be separated evenly.

```js
const people = ["John", "Jack", "Harry", "Charlie", "Jacob"];

const events = [{
  date: "10.10.2021",
  numPeople: 4
}, {
  date: "11.10.2021",
  numPeople: 2
}, {
  date: "12.10.2021",
  numPeople: 1
}, {
  date: "13.10.2021",
  numPeople: 3
}, {
  date: "14.10.2021",
  numPeople: 5
}];

const result = events.map((e) => {
  return {
    ...e,
    people: people.slice(0, e.numPeople)
  }
});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Yeah, thats what I did in first place. But as you can see, this is not even. For example Harry is assigned to every event

Comment: @Mathmada could slice out from people ones needed, then the remaining people are first in the next iteration i.e `[...remaining, ...people].slice`. SO is not a homework coding service, you should make an attempt

Comment: I already made an attempt, and in the end my solution was very confusing and hard to read. That's also the reason why I didn't share this code with you. But in any case, thanks for your afford .